# Using Geometry nodes 3.0 is there a way to animate the camera to follow a bezier segment?

Tags: geometry-nodes

In G/N 3.0 I have a bezier segment converted to mesh with a grid as the profile,  distributed points, and instanced random scaled cubes producing a tunnel around the bezier segment. I am trying to find a way to animate the camera to follow the bezier through the tunnel.

I tried to sample curve and instance the camera using transform node but the camera view is of the original camera not the instance.  I tried to instance an empty instead but when I tried to parent the camera to the empty it is parented to the original empty not the instance.

[image: I disconnected the tunnel part of the node tree]

Comment: Perhaps some screenshots of what you have and what you expect would help?  But if you have Bezier Curve as an independent object, couldn't you just add a follow path constraint?

Comment: I will post a screenshot of my node tree.  The original object is a plane.  I used a Bezier Segment node.  I will try it the way you are suggesting.  Thanks

Comment: If you click on the link you can view my node tree with the tunnel part disconnected so you can see the camera on the curve.

Comment: the movement of the camera isn't the problem. But did you ever make it to "view" through your GN-cam?

Comment: When you instance a camera in GN, it's just a "copy". An empty, referencing the original, not a real camera. It's not available to the outside world, so you can't look through it. If you untick its "As Instance" option for ex, you won't even see it as a shape since cameras (and empties) don't have any geometry to show. If you don't mind creating your curve as an independent obj, do that, bring it in GN with an Object Info, and put a Follow Path on the org. camera to follow it, as Marty Fouts suggested.